# Retrieve indices of letters in a string for python

Tags: python, list

I have a string: "Bob's tank has a big boom!"

I want to use filter to find the indices of where letters of the alphabet appear in the string to save their placement to a list.

```
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

str_ = "Bob's tank has a big boom!"

list_index = list(filter(lambda x: x in alphabet, str_))
```

Currently it just collects all the letters, but i'd like to know their index in the object **str_**.

**Edit for more clarity**

Output should be:

```
[0,1,2,4,6,7...]
[B,o,b,s,t,a...]
```

Comment: Is using `filter` absolutely necessary in your scenario? If not, you could use  [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)

Comment: what is your desired output? i'm confused -))

Comment: What's the desired output? Is it just the index values?

Comment: Yes, so Bob would be indices 0-2. The apostrophe is not part of the alphabet so it skips to index 4 which is the second 's', skips the space and goes to index 6 which is 't' . So it would look like string[0],[1],[2],[4],[6]... etc.

Comment: @GregIven can you edit the question and add the desired output? Maybe you're looking for something like `filter(lambda x: x[1] in alphabet, enumerate(s))`? Also don't use `string` as a variable name as this will conflict with the `string` module.

Comment: @pault yes enumerate was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing out my variable naming faux pas, I changed it to str_ for better naming convention. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension with `enumerate`:

```
[i for i, v in enumerate(str_) if v in alphabet]
```

- `i` is the index, `v` is the value at corresponding index `i`, while `enumerate`-ing over the input string
- `if v in alphabet` does the membership test; if found, the index is saved

**Example:**

```
In [58]: import string
    ...: alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
    ...: 
    ...: str_ = "Bob's tank has a big boom!"
    ...: 

In [59]: [i for i, v in enumerate(str_) if v in alphabet]
Out[59]: [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives each permitted letter and respective position as a list of tuples:

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
string = "Bob's tank has a big boom!"

[(j, i) for i, j in enumerate(string) if j in alphabet]

# [('o', 1), ('b', 2), ('s', 4), ('t', 6), ('a', 7), ('n', 8),
#  ('k', 9), ('h', 11), ('a', 12), ('s', 13), ('a', 15), ('b', 17),
#  ('i', 18), ('g', 19), ('b', 21), ('o', 22), ('o', 23), ('m', 24)]
```